# Concurrent Insert in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration

I have an application which insert bulk record in some tables from multiple hosts. The issue is that while inserting multiple records in one table , it locks the tables and the others threads has to wait until it finishes . Is there any ways that multiple threads can commit its insert in the same table without wait to users . Is there any way in mysql that we can achieve this. 
In other word is there any way in mysql which allow concurrent bulk insert into mysql from multiple threads also bulk Update table while insertion is going on Or bulk update from multiple threads on the same table is allowed or not .

Is there any way we can achieve this in mysql.

Thanks ,

Nitesh Kumar

Comment: Use the InnoDB engine, it provides Row-level Locking insteand of Table-level like in MyISAM.